# Present perfect continuous and past perfect continuous

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

What's the difference between:

1. [...] who **have been** dominating the sport for a couple of years.
2. [...] who **has been** dominating the sport for a couple of years
3. [...] who **had been** dominating the sport for a couple of years.

My main problem here is when to use *has*, *have* and *had*.

Answer (score 2):

- **Have/has been doing** are both [present perfect continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html) forms and they only differ in the number of people you're talking about through the relative pronoun *who*:

  - My school teammate [singular], who ***has* been dominating**...
  - My school teammate*s* [plural], who ***have* been dominating**.

  The present perfect continuous is used to talk about something that started in the past but whose effects are still visible.
- **Had been doing** is a [past perfect continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html) form, which is used to talk about something that started in the past and *continued* to have influence on the events that occurred up until another time *in the past*. Since there's no difference in the singular and plural forms of the English verbs used at a past tense, you can use *who had been doing* both to talk about a singular subject and to refer to a plural one:

  - My school teammate [singular], who ***had* been dominating**...
  - My school teammate*s* [plural], who ***had* been dominating**...

  and the number of people used as a subject can be deduced from the noun *who* is referring to.

You may find useful [this timeline](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/all-english-tenses-timeline-infographic/) [image: this timeline:]
<sub>(source: [englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/english-tenses-infographic-1024x303.jpg))</sub>

the shadowed area for the present perfect continuous and the past perfect continuous tenses indicates that those forms are used to talk about an event that has a (finite) duration up until the present moment (for the former) or a moment in the past (for the latter).

Comment: +1. The *present perfect continuous* can also be defined as an action that began in the past and is still in progress. The *past perfect continuous* for an action that began before another action in the past and that was in progress. Also, the *present perfect continuous* shows the cause of something in the present, and the *past perfect continuous*, the cause of something in the past.